# How to let view display selected field content according to nid

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type "banner" with Field Collection Fieldset, each fieldset is having a image upload field and a text field to enter node ID.

Eg output:

- Image A, nid=1
- Image B, nid=2
- Image C, nid=3

I would like to have a view block, appearing in every page, and shows Image A when the page nid is 1, shows Image B when nid is 2.

I know this should be something related to filter or contextual filter, but I can't get the correct steps to configure. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

Add a **contextual filter** of

> content: nid

then do as the picture below.

[image]